# Are multiple exits viable to flatten a long Python function?

Tags: python, coding-style

I have a long Python function of that structure:

```
def the_function(lots, of, arguments):

    return_value = None

    if some_important_condition:

        # a lot of stuff here

        return_value = "some value"

    else:

        # even more stuff here

        return_value = "some other value"

    return return_value
```

One problem is that both the `if` and the `else` block contain more than one screenful of code. It is easy to lose track of the indentation, or having to scroll up to see in what condition we are at the moment.

One idea to improve this would be to split it up in several functions:

```
def case_true(lots, of, arguments):

    # a lot of stuff here

    return "some value"

def case_false(lots, of, arguments):

    # even more stuff here

    return "some other value"

def the_function(lots, of, arguments):

    return_value = None

    if some_important_condition:

        return_value = case_true(lots, of, arguments)

    else:

        return_value = case_false(lots, of, arguments)

    return return_value
```

but I am not sure whether this cleans things up, considering the argument juggling.

Another idea would be to use multiple exit points:

```
def the_function(lots, of, arguments):

    if some_important_condition:

        # a lot of stuff here

        return "some value"

    # even more stuff here

    return "some other value"
```

but several coding styles advice against multiple exit points, especially when they are screens apart.

The question is: what would be a preferred, pythonic way to make the original construct more read- and maintainable?

Comment: I think this is subjective enough it really belongs on Programmers, not SO. For what it's worth, I would argue that returning when you have a return value is best - it's more efficient, and clearer to me. If your function is multiple screens of code, then I would argue you should split it into more functions.

Comment: I've found that the ease of passing parameters and return values makes my Python functions shorter than they would be in other languages - there's a lot less friction in breaking things up. Check out the `*args` convention for parameter passing.

Comment: If you can't see what's going on in a single function block without scrolling, chances are it should be refactored into smaller, logical functions.

Comment: @MarkRansom, to me `*args` conflicts with "explicit is better than implicit" and "readability counts". ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to have several exit points in a function, the requirement of only a single exit point is an old convention, dating back to the days where programming languages didn't have exception handling and it made sense to have a single exit point to centralize error handling. The existence of exceptions makes that old convention obsolete.

There are situations where having multiple exit points is the way to go, *even* when enforcing the single function exit point policy - for example, [guard clauses](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GuardClause) at the top of a function require a quick return from a function  "if parameters are bad, or the bulk of the function is obviously inappropriate", in this case makes a lot of sense "bailing out at the top, before any meaningful work has been done. Otherwise, you'll need huge if statements that cover the bulk of the function, giving you yet another level of indentation".

For completeness' sake, here's an [explanation](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SingleFunctionExitPoint) expanding on my point.

Comment: From the link: "Otherwise, you'll need huge if statements that cover the bulk of the function, giving you yet another level of indentation -- yuck!" Very nice.

Comment: If the answer in addition hinted at the [GuardClause](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GuardClause), it would be acceptable (in the SO sense).

Comment: @fbmd added a reference to guard clauses, as suggested ;) . I'm quoting verbatim from the wiki, their definition is spot-on.

Answer (score 2):

The golden rule is: one function can have several return points, but **as long as it enhances readability**, and if your code is so massive, I'm afraid there will not be any difference between returning, and copying into a variable that will be returned.

I think your problem is more about the design, level of abstraction and semantics of your routine.

These questions might help you:

- Does the routine have functional cohesion? i.e.: it does only and only one thing. Not something like calculate revenues, print them, send them to server and go for a walk with the dog.
- Does the function have more than 7 arguments? If so, most probably the level of abstraction of your routine is not appropriated.

It would help if you post a little bit more information on the details of your routine (what it does, what it returns, what arguments). It might be that you are better off using two classes for that...

But, as a general answer, I would say that you better analyze the individual actions, factor them out in small functions with good cohesion, and turn your function into a sequential caller of these small functions, rather than having it do the work. And the approach of having only two functions to case_true, and case_false is probably wrong, since it can very well be that you have similar actions in both functions (for true, and false) and you are coding them twice.